# Actively developed text browser

Tags: lynx, links

I am looking for "the modern" lynx/links/elinks fork or equivalent that's actively maintained and can be considered the most advanced of the genre, please.

I have looked at this already: http://web-browsers.findthebest.com/compare/18-25-26/ELinks-Web-Browser-vs-Lynx-Web-Browser-vs-Links-Web-Browser

This question is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604666/elinks-or-lynx but allows consideration of other programs as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/current/) is actively maintained, but mostly for bug fixes.

The [last release](http://links.twibright.com/download/ChangeLog) of [Links 2](http://links.twibright.com/) was on 2011-08-10. The [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) [fork](http://elinks.cz/history.html) still has an active [developer mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/elinks-dev@linuxfromscratch.org/) with [occasional bug fixes](http://repo.or.cz/w/elinks.git), but hasn't seen a release since 2009.

[W3m](http://sourceforge.net/projects/w3m/) is actively maintained, though no major feature has been added in several years. The latest version is w3m 0.5.3 released on 2011-01-15.

There isn't a single project that's more advanced than the rest. W3m's killer feature is its superior rendering of frames, tables and other visual elements. Links's killer feature is its experimental JavaScript support.