# Is there any web browser that uses keybinding apart from uzbl?

Tags: software-rec, browser

I have just found out about [uzbl](http://www.uzbl.org/) but for some reason it crashes with segmentation fault when I log into gmail (Arch). I don't have the time nor the knowledge of dealing with this segmentation fault so I have thought about using another browser of that type. Are there any?

Thanks.

Comment: Must that be a whole browser? Firefox+[Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/) or Chrome+[Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) would provide similar features but in addition you could use other accessibility extensions too.

Comment: I think it has, I like the minimalism of the command line...

Comment: See also [Actively developed text browser](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20158)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few:

- [Vimprobable](http://www.vimprobable.org/) - WebKit and Vim-like keybindings. Comes in two versions.
- [dwb](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95589) - a tiling web browser developed by an Arch Linux user (again, WebKit)
- [Conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) - if you prefer Emacs bindings
- [Surf](http://surf.suckless.org/) - another suckless product...
- [xombrero](https://opensource.conformal.com/wiki/xombrero) - "a minimalist web browser with sophisticated security features designed-in" (from the linked wiki page)

Comment: Nice, I'm toying arroun with Conkeror now.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a ready-to-use, yet lightweight solution like `uzbl`, definitely try [**luakit**](http://luakit.org/projects/luakit/). From my experience, it is much more stable and intuitive than uzbl. It has tabs, uses some vim-like key bindings and is fully configurable and extensible.